# How to select data from a table by condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select all data from `table2` while sum of 'Amount' is less then 'Value' from `table1`.

Example:

**table1**

```
Id          Value
1           24,00
2           13,00
3           2,00
4           5,00
```

**table2**

```
Id         Amount   
1           3,00    
1           5,00    
1           5,00    
1           6,00    
1           8,00    
1           9,00    
2           6,00    
2           11,00   
2           45,00   
3           2,00    
3           4,00    
4           4,00    
4           6,00    
4           8,00    
4           9,00
```

***Result:***

```
Id         Amount
1           3,00    
1           5,00    
1           5,00    
1           6,00
2           6,00    
3           2,00    
4           4,00
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried using WHILE loop and subqueries

Comment: Please add all attempts to the question by editing it.

Comment: Your results aren't showing the SUM of anything, just individual rows.

Comment: Perhaps `SELECT t2.Id, t2.Amount FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.Id = t1.Id AND t2.Amount < t1.Value`? But hard to say for sure, since you mention SUM().